# OOP use database connection for other class

Tags: php, mysql, oop

Below is the code for database connection. & there are more methods under it.
To keep it simple i decided to make a separate class for other methods.So is there anyway i can connect to database when instantiating other class.
**Db.php**

```
class Db{
private static $_instance = null;
private $_db;

private function __construct(){
    try{
        $this->_db = new PDO('mysql:host = localhost;dbname=db_xoo', 'root', '');
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}

public static function get_instance(){
    if(!isset(self::$_instance)){
        return self::$_instance = new Db();     
    }
    else{
        return self::$_instance;
    }
}
```

**Other.php**

```
<?php
class Other{
    .
    .
    .
    public function blah(){
        database queries..
    }
    .
    .
}
?>
```

Now when i instantiate class other.What should i add in `other.php` so that it can make automatic connection to database instead of calling `Db::get_instance()` everytime before creating `$test = new Other()`

Answer (score 0):

use constract in other class

like this

```
class Other{
    private $_db;

    private function __construct(){
        $this->_db = Db::get_instance();
    }
    public function blah(){
        database queries.. $this->_db->query()
    }
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: Okay but if i want to use static methods in other.php . How will it make connection to database?

Comment: use `$_db` for connection to database in other class